# point particle explanation of refraction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, refraction, point-particles

Is there an explanation of refraction using the point particle model?

Most explanations I have seen use the wave model or particles with width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply plug a delta function into the 1st Born Approximation.

The resulting scattered field is then a scaled version of the Fourier Transform of a delta function, although the physicality of this result is questionable as a delta particle is likely to capture the instrument response of your system.

The scattering from multiple point particles by way of the 1st Born Approximation is a typical approximation used in Dynamic Light Scattering (DLS) theory and is often called the structure function. Although it is generally desired to remove the structure to obtain information about the actual particles...

Comment: @BenitoCiaro Your comment sounds a little anti-intellectual. These fields are perfectly measurable, so calling them "construct without any known physical analog" is incorrect. Indeed, DLS methods are used in industry to characterize the content of aqueous solutions. Scattering from particles in like electrons was first measured, then explained.

Comment: @BenitoCiaro Its not purely mathematical, it summarizes the behavior of particle in a material. Sometimes the material is difficult to understand (like the luminiferous ether) but its not any less real then the following gif: http://www.jjvernon.com/tpb1/Resources/peoplewave.gif

In a typical graduate physics class you would go from the equation of motion of an electron to the polarization and the resulting fields. The "action at a distance element is not important. Indeed, classical theories don't appear to act at a distance.